# LogParser Lizard

Tags: file, logging, log4net, file-access, logparser

I am using LogParser Lizard to parse Log4Net files and when I am trying to do a query such as: SELECT * FROM "C:\Logs*.log". I get an error saying "The process cannot access the file [...] because it is being used by another process" (correct, it is my web app deployed in IIS that is currently writing to it). Is there a way to circumvent this behavior and still open the file for reading even if it is currently in use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is a little old, but I'll give my work-around anyway.  Copy the log files to a temp folder.  Then use Log Parser Lizard on the copies.